# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() (discord.py editing message)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
message = await ctx.send("Hey guys")
await asyncio.sleep(1)
1 = [f"a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "yo", "wow"]
for i in range(1):
 await ctx.message.edit(random.choice(1))
```

I'm trying to make my discord bot edit its message and randomly pick one of the words in 1 but for some reason i keep getting TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len() i am pretty new to python i've only been coding for 4 months

Comment: The code you've posted has a `SyntaxError` for trying to assign to the literal `1` before the `random.choice` which I assume is what's causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you probably don't want to use a number as a variable name. Thats going to cause some bad interactions. Rename your list to `words` or something.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this problem when reading information from an external file and using it in my class.
In fact, the variable did not refer to a specific data such as:

> 1 or c.

Refers to a class address.

In fact, you have access to the same address:

```
<__main__.yourClass object at 0x0000012DF86AF0D0>.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).